# Do Preference Attributes relate to data extension subscribers at all?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I've never found a way where preference management attributes or even profile center attributes come into play when solely using data extensions. How would we utilize, for example, the preference of a subscriber who only wants to receive Plain-Text emails if we use data extensions only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to run an automation that updates the All Subscriber list for the `HTML Email` column and set it as `false` to receive only Plain-Text emails. Extract your data from your data extension and import it into All Subscribers

In Automation Studio:
**Data Extract > File Transfer > Import**

Then map your `HTML Email` to your Subscriber Key and Email Address.

[image: Map appropriate fields]

Comment: Can this process be done the other way as well? Data Extract All Subscribers info > File Transfer and Import into Data Extension?

Comment: No but you query _Subscribers or manually Export.