# Query Preference Attributes

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-views, preference-center

Does anyone has any idea on how to query the Preference Attributes? I can see them in All Subscribers, but I can't find a way to query them.

[image]

I tried doing a query activity on EnterpriseAttribute Data View and this is the error I get:
[image]

These are the fields of the Data Extension in which I want to save the data:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for the _EnterpriseAttribute Data view that is documented here:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_enterpriseattribute.htm&type=5

Emphasis:

> NOTE This data view is for Enterprise 2.0 clients only. When profile attributes are created in Enterprise 2.0 accounts, new columns are added to the _EnterpriseAttribute table. Data view queries in Enterprise 2.0 accounts can return results from profile attribute columns in addition to the columns listed here.

> NOTE This data view is only available in the Parent account and cannot be used in a business unit.

Comment: I tried, but I get this error: "An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Invalid column name 'HTML Emails'."

Comment: pls edit your question with the query you tried, and pls note where you tried it (automation or query studio) to rule out syntax errors

Comment: Line 3 of your query says `AS HTMLEmails` without space, Line 4 or your query says `AS TestAlex` without space. Your DE fields each contain spaces.

Also, you query for `HTML Emails` and the field in your preference Attributes is called `HTML Email`

Comment: You're right. Sorry, my bad, I fordot to refres the page. They are actually without space. The problem is on the 3rd row on my query when I try to retrieve the 'HTML Emails'

Comment: Sounds like, problem solved? then please mark as accepted :)

Comment: Is not solved, the problem still persists. I can't retrieve the `HTML Emails` attribute. every time I try I receive that error `An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Invalid column name 'HTML Emails'`

Comment: Have you read this part of my last comment? 

You query for `HTML Emails` and the field in your preference Attributes is called `HTML Email`

Comment: @JonasLamberty I have the same issue with `HTML Email` field, the error shows up `An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Invalid column name 'HTML Email'.` while I don't have any issue with my new preference attribute I just created

Comment: hm. interesting :D i wonder how my question was accepted. The linked docs by now state: `NOTE Preference attributes, such as HTML Email, aren't available in this data view` - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_enterpriseattribute.htm&type=5 - i cannot seem to query it off Ent._subscribers either, but the import screen to All Subscribers does still show it. Check here:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261504/do-preference-attributes-relate-to-data-extension-subscribers-at-all
- last ditch: tracking extract > Extract subscribers, reimport to a DE.